# Get a form action/url with jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, asp.net-mvc-2

How do I get the action url from a form with jquery?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Get the form, ask for the `action` attribute:

```
$('#myForm').attr('action');
```

Comment: Great answer. I was curious if `attr()` was the best way, as opposed to the newer `prop()`. Turns out [they both return something different](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34212885/3965565).

Answer (score 37):

## Need the *full* action url instead of just the basename?

Generally it's better to use `prop()` instead of `attr()` when grabbing these sorts of values. (This [prop() vs attr() stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5874652/3965565) explains why.)

However, in this instance, [@JAAulde answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5620438/3965565) is exactly what *I* needed, but not might be what *you* need. You might want the full action url.

### Consider this html form start tag:

```
<form action="handler.php" method="post" id="myForm">
```

#### attr() returns the exact action value:

```
$('#myForm').attr('action'); 
// returns 'handler.php'
```

#### prop() returns the full action url:

```
$('#myForm').prop('action');
// returns 'http://www.example.com/handler.php'
```

[Check out the cool ascii table in this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5884994/3965565) to learn more.

Answer (score 4):

Try this one:

```
var formAction = $('#form')[0].action;
```

Or on form sumit:

```
 $("#form").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var frmAction=this.action;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

To use the action attribute of a form use:

```
$( '#myForm' ).attr( 'action' );
```

like @JAAulde said.

To use an entered value from a form use:

```
$('#myInput').val();
```

Comment: Forms themselves don't have values, the form elements contained within them do. Your comment seems a little confused.

Comment: Yes, #myInput refers to an input element within the form, where a URL might be entered.

Comment: Ok, if that's the case, the `#myInput` is likely not to have an `action` attr.  @RoryMcCrossan's point is that it won't have both