# How to get action of form using jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, viewengine

I have form in my page, I am using ajax.beginform(). Inside this form I have submit button. On submit of input button I want action of form.
 Following is the piece of code which may be useful for you to understand.

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("FormContainer", "Form",  new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId =      "HeaderMain", HttpMethod = "Post", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
        {
 <input name="" type="submit" value="Request" class="propel-viewDetailsButton" />

}
```

On click of input button I want to call java scrip t function where I want action of a form

Comment: I guess this might be useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620420/get-a-forms-action-url-with-jquery

Comment: How many forms do you have on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".propel-viewDetailsButton").click(function() {
    var action = this.closest("form").prop("action");
}
```

Should do it :)

Comment: It would even be better if the form had an "id".

Comment: Indeed - it would also be better if the button had an ID as well, so it could be targeted directly, as using a class selector could mean another element on the same page (with the same class) would also be selected. But he didn't ask us to give him best practices :)

Comment: Oh, you are right. :D But nice of us to discuss this here so that he can see it :)