# How to get url from form action? like scraping or parsing in php

Tags: php

I want to get URL from HTML form action. How can I get this in PHP? The form tag like

```
<form method="post" action="my.aspx? id="aspnetForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">

</form>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get a forms action/url with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620420/get-a-forms-action-url-with-jquery)

Comment: PHP is a server-side language ... can you explain in more detail what it is you are trying to do ?

Comment: are you grabbing/scraping the the page, and trying to parse the html to get the action?

Comment: I want to read html page and try to get the url section from that.

Comment: Firstly, that code is invalid (although I'm assuming the `?` should be a `"`) And secondly: What are you talking about? When do you want the action URL (on/after page request)? How is the form given the URL? Read the question from our point of view and then try answering it. **It's hard work**

Comment: Ok let me more clear i want to read a page which contain form with action.Now i want to get only the url form action portion.I think this can be done using file_get_content like some function but not sure yet.

Comment: you can use DOM of php - just render it and take the attribute you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to load the HTML with DOM and then extract the information using xpath:

```
// create a DOM document object and load your html
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHtml($yourHtml);

// create an Xpath selector for the document
$selector = new DOMXpath($doc);

// the following query will return all <form> elements
// you may refine it
$result = $selector->query('//form');

// get the first item (to keep the example simple)
$form = $result->item(0);

// get the value of the action attribute
$url = $form->getAttribute('action');
```

Comment: I am doing like that
 $url = 'http://google.com';
$data = file_get_contents($url, 0, $context);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHtml($data);
But got error htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity,

Comment: Ignore the parse warnings or suppress them using the '@' operator .. currently testing my example :)

Comment: If i ignore them how to ignore this one Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on a non-object

Comment: Check my update. Use '//form' as the query string.

Comment: Thanks your code rocks.Great

Answer (score 0):

You can use regexp. But I think for you will simple make next steps:

1. with **stristr** function detect begin of form tag - search string "<form"
2. use **stristr** again for find begin of string "action="
3. use **substr** for truncate first 7 chars to begin url string
4. use **strpos** for detect first space after url string
5. use **substr** for get string of url
6. delete space and quotes from this string. Use for this **str_replace** or **trim** function

I think this will help you for study how you can parse any html tags and others things.

Answer (score 0):

you can get like this..

```
      <?php
       $string = <<<XML
       <form method="post" action="my.aspx? id="aspnetForm" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>
       XML;

      $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

      $att = 'action';
      $attribute = $xml->form[0]->attributes()->$att; // answer
      ?>
```